# How to delete a table cell in php

Tags: php

I have 3 fields one of them is a type file that i select according an id:

```
 $qryz="SELECT * FROM claims_follow_up.Reconciliation_Details where   id_rd ='$id_rd' ";
    $res = mysqli_query($dbc, $qryz);
  $dd=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

<label> Client Name</label> 
 <input type="text" name= "Client_Name"  value="<?=$dd['Client_Name']?></br>
 <label>Activity</label> 
 <input type="text" name= "Activity"  value="<?=$dd['Activity']?> " ></br>
<label>PDF_Report1</label> 
 <a href="uploads/<?php echo $dd['PDF_Report1'] ?>"  target="_blank"><?php echo $dd['PDF_Report1'] ?></a> 
  <?php echo '<a href="del_file.php?id_rd='.$dd['id_rd'].' " class="btn btn-primary btn-xs btn-danger" onclick="return confirm(\'Do you really want to delete this file ?\')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>Delete file #1</a>';?>
```

In my table the file column name is **PDF_Report1**

How can i delete only the content of **PDF_Report1** ? 
In page **del_file.php**, something like:

```
  $id_rd  = $_GET["id_rd"] ;  
 $sql="delete PDF_Report1 from claims_follow_up.Reconciliation_Details where id_rd = '$id_rd' ";
```

Thanks

Comment: you cannot delete column from single row, you can either `drop column` for entire table, `delete` whole row or `update` column value

Comment: thank you so much i didn't think of update query, i use update and that's ok..